# How do I make a mod_rewrite rule that uses the sub-domain name to rewrite the URL?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, url

How do I make a mod_rewrite rule that uses the sub-domain name to rewrite the URL?

What I want to do is something like this:

Forward requests FROM  http://agency1.company.com  TO:  https://appname.company.com/appname/login.jsp?agencyName=agency1

It doesn't need to be a live proxy; It can just be a meta-refresh type of thing or a basic URL forward.   Seems like this would be a common scenerio but I can't find an example on the internet.   Lots of examples on the net of a URI rewrite but not many concerning a full URL rewrite (as I am trying to do above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use Back-references.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+)\.domain\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://appname.company.com/appname/login.jsp?agencyName=%1 [R=301,L]
```

However, note this will end up redirecting again once the 301 is followed, IF the redir is to happen on HTTP only use the following block.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+)\.domain\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://appname.company.com/appname/login.jsp?agencyName=%1 [R=301,L]
```

%1 refers to the first regex "capture" in the RewriteCond line, if you were to utilize mutliple points %2 and so on would become available.

Comment: That worked although I discovered that if the URL has a space in it, that the URL in the rewrite rule has to be quoted.

Comment: In those cases wrapping the rule in quotes ("") often works, not sure if the %1 back ref works in those quotes though, will need some experimentation

Comment: Also, doing it this way for SSL requires that I need to have a different SSL cert for each subdomain  (wildcard cert of course).  This explains why this rewrite method is not so common and I probably shouldn't have tried going down this path.  A URI rewrite method would work better: using only 1 certificate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use RewriteCond on the HTTP_HOST value to do this.  There's a couple examples of this usage in the [Apache URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html).  You would do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}                 ^[^.]+\.company\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://appname.company.com/$1?agencyName=%1 [R,L,QSA]
```

This is untested, and might not work as is, but should point you in the right direction.